# Dual problem of $\min_{r \in \mathbb R^m, w \in \mathbb R^n} - \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1 + r_i)$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the optimization problem with $X \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $y \in \mathbb R^n$
\begin{equation}
    \min_{r \in \mathbb R^m, w \in \mathbb R^n} - \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1 + r_i) \\
\end{equation}
subject to  $r = Xw- y$ and $r_i \geq 0.$
*Derive the dual problem.*

So the Langrangian is
$$ L(r, w, \lambda, \mu) = - \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1 + r_i) - \langle \lambda, r \rangle + \langle \mu, Xw - y - r) $$
with $\lambda \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}^m$ und $\mu \in \mathbb R^m$.

The dual function is defined as
$$ q(\lambda, \mu) = \inf_{r, w} L(r, w, \lambda, \mu). $$
How does one find this infimum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrangian is convex and differentiable in the primal variables $(r,w)$, so to find the infimum you can simply set the gradient to zero. The $j$th partial with respect to $r$ is
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial r_j} = -\frac{1}{1+r_j} - \lambda_j - \mu_j,
\end{equation*}
and the gradient with respect to $w$ is
\begin{equation*}
\nabla_w L= X^\top \mu.
\end{equation*}
Setting these to zero, we obtain the system of equations
\begin{align*}
1 + (\lambda_j+\mu_j)(1+r_j) &= 0, \\
X^\top \mu&=0.
\end{align*}
The second condition is a constraint on $\mu$ and is needed since the Lagrangian is affine (and therefore unbounded below) in $w$. Solving the first equation for $r_j$ we obtain
\begin{equation*}
r_j = -1-\frac{1}{\lambda_j+\mu_j}.
\end{equation*}
Substituting these results back into the Lagrangian, we find that the dual function becomes
\begin{equation*}
q(\lambda,\mu) = \begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
-\sum_{j=1}^n\log(-\tfrac{1}{\lambda_j+\mu_j}) + \sum_{j=1}^n(\lambda_j+\mu_j+1)-\mu^\top y & \text{if $X^\top \mu = 0$}, \\
-\infty & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Clearly, the dual problem amounts to maximizing the top case of $q$ subject to the constraints $X^\top \mu = 0$ and $\lambda\ge 0$. Also note that the dual function imposes an implicit constraint on the pair $(\lambda,\mu)$, since we must have $\frac{1}{\lambda_j+\mu_j}<0$ for all $j$.